# Infinite loop redirection while connecting with phpCAS in cakephp 3

Tags: php, authentication, session, cakephp, phpcas

I am migrating my project from Cakephp 2 to Cakephp 3. So after i decide to migrate the phpCas authentication, there is an infinite redirection before the navigator decide to stop the process. After a lot of research, I found that the problem was that my session variable is not kept after redirection. I looked at the session numbers present and indeed with each redirection the session id is different and the information about my user has disappeared. I configured the session using the default mode of php in the app.php. I also thought that the session should find its number after the redirection using cookies and that maybe mine were not activated. When I check the phpCas log, the login is fine and i find my user name. Everything goes well, only my session variable is not kept after redirection.

Comment: sorry, what is question? Have you any code?

Comment: Problem solved, it was the hour read by cakephp and the duration of the cookies. Just change the timezone and session.cookie_lifetime in app.php.